# parsing JSON issue with json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I am currently working on a project with AngularJS and I am trying to make login and session.
So far I am being successful, when I pass the correct paramters it works, but when i input wrong parameters, such as null userid and password or filled userid and null password it doesnt work. I guess it has something to do with the parsing of JSON by php

loginCtrl calls the loginService login function. The data var is user and password (trying first with plain text then I'll try something more fun). it then sends this to build_session.php to parse it as json and match the login and password. if it is correct it authenticates. Here is the code.

loginService.js

```
'use strict';

app.factory('loginService', function($http, $location, sessionService){
    return{
        login:function(data, scope){
            var $promise = $http.post('data/build_session.php', data);
            $promise.then(function(msg){
                var uid = msg.data;
                console.debug(uid); // <<<<<<<<<<<< DEBUG
                if(uid){ //ISSUE IS HAPPENING HERE
                    scope.msgTxt = "";
                    sessionService.set('uid', uid); //THIS IS CALLING SESSIONSERVICE
                    $location.path('/historicoReceitas');
                    scope.moduleState = "loggedIn";

                }
```

sessionService.js

```
'use strict'

app.factory('sessionService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        set:function(key,value){
            return sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);
        },
        get:function(key){
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        destroy:function(key){
            $http.post('data/destroy_session.php');
            return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    };
}])
```

build_session.php

```
<?php 
    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); // <<<Error
    if($user->cpf == '311.986.988-02' && $user->password == '1234'){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['uid'] = uniqid('_ang');
        print $_SESSION['uid'];
    }
?>
```

When i input the correct data prom cpf and password, the debug returns this:

```
_ang53d9d09948e99
```

But when i input incorrect data (no login or password) it returns something like this:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Paolo Cezar\Dropbox\RMO\data\build_session.php on line 3

which i guess is some php default error page or something. I've seen some complaints on how json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); handles JSON but i didnt come to a good response.

I have used these two tutorials as basis for my code:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y6LM4Y_K6c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz5G2A_enAk

Comment: check what $user is containing. by dumping it.

Comment: Check your browser's *Network* console and make sure it's posting the expected JSON payload

Comment: I tested now at my work, where the php server is a ubuntuserver and the problem does not occurr. On my laptop where, i got this error, the server is WAMP and it was installed last year (maybe 2 years ago). Do you think this may have to do with server configuration?

Comment: @phil I checked and it said that the variable was undefined.
it seems that when i input nothing on cpf and password the parameters are pushed to php as undefined resulting in error. I used the array_key_exists() function to check if the variables where undefined and  and it worked.

thanks for the advice =)